# Bad Request on all Social Tables API Check In

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to check in a guest using the API.  I'm Starting with the Social Tables developer API console to verify the format and that the information is set correctly.  I'm specifically using:

**/4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests/{guest_id}/checkin**

After filling in the guestlist_id, guest_id, and checked_in fields I always reveice back:

```
{
  "code": "BadRequestError",
  "message": "{\"checked_in\":[\"Checked in can't be blank\"]}"
}
```

An example of what I'm using for the checked_in field (based on the example value) is:

```
{
  "id": "{guest_id}",
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "Jones"
}
```

I've also tried:

```
{
  "id": "{guest_id}",
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "Jones",
  "checked_in_status": {
    "checked_in": 1,
    "checked_in_at": "2017-02-23T19:40:20.576Z",
    "checked_out_at": "2017-02-23T19:40:20.576Z"
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I could understand if there was a problem sending the request from an app, but using the developer API console I would've expected it to work.  Is the documentation wrong?  How would I go about checking in a guest?

Thank you in advance to anybody that can help clear this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out. The API Example Body Value is indeed incorrect. The proper body would be:

```
{
  checked_in: 1,           // values can be 0 = None, 1 = Checked-In, 2 = Checked-Out
  event_name: "Test Event" // this is optional. Used if you have Tag Notifications set up
}
```

I'll go ahead and update the documentation for you. Feel free to post again if you have any other issues.

Comment: Trying that still failed.  When I used `checked_in` instead then it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Typo. Sorry for that